# Creating a generic update counter method

Tags: scala, playframework, slick

I'm trying to create a generic counter update method for a particular table.

My table has many columns that are simply counters, and in my application I need to increment/decrement these counters.

I was trying to create a method like this:

```
private def updateCounter(column: String, id: Int, incr: Int)(implicit session: Session): Unit = {
  sqlu"update table1 set $column = $column + $incr where id=$id".first
}
```

I would then create a method that would call this (I don't want to expose this method outside of this Dao class).

I am getting this error:

```
[PSQLException: ERROR: syntax error at or near "$1" Position: 20]
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try replacing `$column` by `#$column`. [`$` is used for bind variables](http://slick.typesafe.com/doc/3.1.1/sql.html#string-interpolation) which is not suitable for identifiers like column or table names, whereas [`#$` is a mere string replacement like the `s""` string interpolation](http://slick.typesafe.com/doc/3.1.1/sql.html#splicing-literal-values).

Also make sure that your column variable is not vulnerable to SQL injections.